# .htaccess RewriteRule to change ? to &

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, google-ads-api

I have problem tracking visitors from Adwords. They do not show in analytics, because of bad url formating. Spent hours to trying edit my current .htaccess, but found no solution. My current .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !(upload||media|admin|index\.php)
RewriteRule .* template.php?seo_url=$0& [PT,L]
```

So when visitor comes from adwords, url in browser looks like: 
`http://www.example.com/section?gclid=XXXXX`
Server side url is: `http://www.example.com?seo_url=section?gclid=XXXXX`

Could you help me to change .htaccess to do server side url like `http://www.example.com?seo_url=section&gclid=XXXXX`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What should actually happen is that the original query string should be discarded and only the RewriteRule query string should remain. To avoid that, use the [QSA flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa). Something like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ template.php?seo_url=$1 [QSA,PT,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped. With one link you saved me a day or maybe more

Answer (score -1):

Try a RewriteRule like this:

```
RewriteRule .* template.php?seo_url=%{REQUEST_URI}&%{QUERY_STRING} [PT,L]
```

Comment: True, but its still a correct answer. Anyway I added your objection.

Comment: still, RewriteRule only matches the URL before the query

Comment: If you know it so well, why dont you help a bit? Will `RewriteRule .* template.php?seo_url=%{REQUEST_URI}&%{QUERY_STRING}` work?

Comment: Uhm, probably not. See my answer and also http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString